# NSIS MUI2, несколько галочек для принятия лицензионного соглашения

Tags: nsis

```
; -------------------------------
; Start
  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  OutFile "1.exe"
;--------------------------------
;Modern UI Configuration

  !define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE  
  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE
  !define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE
  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  !define MUI_UNINSTALLER
  !define MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE  

;--------------------------------
;Language
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Russian"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX_TEXT "I &accept the terms of service"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE License.txt

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

;-------------------------------- 
;Installer Sections     
Section "install"
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Hello world install!"
SectionEnd
```

Приведенный код разрешит установку программы только после постановки галочки о принятии лицензии, но нужно еще несколько галочек обязательных, как это сделать?